# Understanding hierarchy method calling

Tags: java, class, methods, hierarchy

I have an issue in understanding what is the hierarchy in which the methods between classes are called. I have this code here:

```
class X {
   protected int v = 0;

   public X() {
      v = v + 10;
   }

   public void proc(X p) {
      System.out.println(43);
   }
}

class Y extends X {
   public Y() {
     v = v + 5;
   }

   public void proc(X p) {
     System.out.println(57);
   }

   public int getV() {
     return v;
   }
}

class Z extends Y {
   public Z() {
     v = v + 9;
   }

   public void proc(Z p) {
     System.out.println(39);
   }
}

class Main {
   public static void main(String argv[]) {
     X x = new Z();
     Y y = new Z();
     Z z = new Z();
     x.proc(z);
     System.out.println(y.getV());
   }
}
```

The data that the code prints is `57 24`. So, in the case, the method `proc` is called on an object of a X reference but a Z instance, so I thought that the method from the X class will be called, but apparently it calls the one from the Y class. Why is that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x`'s static (compile time) type is `X`. Therefore for `x.proc(z)` the compiler can only choose from methods declared in the `X` class (or super classes of `X`). Therefore only `public void proc(X p)` is applicable (`proc(Z p)` of class `Z` is not applicable, since class `X` has no method with such signature).

Now, since the runtime type of the instance referenced by `x` is `Z`, and since `proc(X p)` is overridden by class `Y`, which is a super class of class `Z`, in runtime the `proc(X p)` method of `Y` is executed. That's the behavior of method overriding.